# How to skip_before_filter for a redirect in a action method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-headers

I have a controller which has several methods and one of them has a redirect at the end.

```
def launch
  do_something
  params[:hey] = "heyo"
  redirect_to("/tasks")
end
```

All actions has a before_filter which sets some access control headers.
What i want is;

I want to have this before filter for "launch" method, but not for the redirect in it.
How can i achieve this ?

When i set this below, it removes filter for both launch method and "/tasks" redirect, but i only want to remove it for the redirect.

```
skip_filter :set_access_control_headers, :only => :launch
```

Thanks in advance!

Update:

This method lives in an engine, that's why I have different access control headers than main application. I do not want to mess with main applications code since i create specific engine and routes for each customer.

And the redirect in the end goes to main application.

Comment: is `tasks` an action in your controller ? what about just excluding that action: `skip_filter :set_access_control_headers, :only => :tasks`

Comment: Just updated the question, redirect goes to main application, this controller lives in a rails engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can set param in your redirect and in filter check if param is not exist than skip

Example: redirect_to edit_multiple_items_path, :notice => 'items updated', {:page => ##, :method => 'GET'}

Comment: Redirect takes request from an engine to rails application, main application does not have this headers already. It is the before_filter in engine that sets these headers. and i don't want those to be sent to main application but keep it in all engine methods.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because I focused too much on doing it the "Rails" way.

I fixed the issue by simply removing the headers manually just before the redirect and it all worked fine now.

```
  headers.delete('Access-Control-Allow-Origin')
  headers.delete('Access-Control-Request-Method')
  headers.delete('Access-Control-Allow-Methods')

  redirect(/tasks?#{options.to_query})
```

Thanks for the answers though!